# Formatação de String - Alinhamento PYTHON

Tags: python, string, formatação

minha dúvida é, no lugar do :>6, eu queria que o usuário pudesse escolher a quantia de caracteres a serem alinhados para a direita, por exemplo, ali no lugar do 6, eu colocaria a variável n.

Porém o python acusa um erro, dando a entender que só se aceita números que são diretamente colocados ali como parâmetro, não consigo jogar a variável n que já é int por sinal.
Tem alguma forma de fazer isso?

```
def staircase(n):
        grade = "#"
        vezes = 1
        for i in range(0, n):
            print(f"{grade:>6}")
            vezes += 1
            grade = "#" * vezes
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        n = int(input())
    
        staircase(n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta colocar a variável também entre chaves:

```
print(f"{grade:>{n}}")
```

Assim o valor da variável `n` será interpolado na *string* e ainda será considerado como parâmetro da formatação do valor de `grade`.

Mais informações, veja a [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Comment: Grato Woss, não sabia dessa interpolação.

Comment: caramba - eu não sabia dessa - até antes de ver aqui, eu achava que tinha que ser em 2 etapas - primerio criar uma string com os parâmetros de formatação, e aí formatar de novo para incluir os parâmetros: print(f"{{grade: >{n}}}".format(grade=grade) )